# I really need help with my question, how do I get help?

Tags: discussion, support

I am a new user with only one question, but I really need help with it.  I am new to Linux and therefor have no ability to answer or edit questions, and without a rep of 20 I am not able to chat with people asking if someone can help me out.

I have taken great steps to avoid wasting anybody's time by investigating and completing every step given on related questions, in most cases more than once. I have posted my question (5 points for me!) and someone edited it (thanks!) but I still need a response.

Here is my question, if anyone here can answer that's great, or if someone can forward it along to a forum or chat room or something, that'll work, too!

[No sound output, but is recognizing device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833556/no-sound-output-but-is-recognizing-device)

Comment: Looks like you have > 20 rep now.

Comment: But.. how?

So glad I can enter the chat rooms now, feels kind of arbitrary, though...

Answer (score 10):

> I really need help with my question, how do I get help?

The answer to your question is "patience".

We can't force people to be able to assist you.  Users also may ask you for clarification on things, or for you to comment on your own post or edit your question for information if there's not enough there to give a clear fix.

> I am new to Linux and therefor have no ability to answer or edit questions, and without a rep of 20 I am not able to chat with people asking if someone can help me out.

Well, firstly, we were all new at some point; "no ability" to answer or edit questions means nothing.  You can get rep by posting good questions, too.

As for the chat rep issue, I don't think that's an issue anymore - the system says you have 21 rep right now.

We can't really suggest to people to help you or not.  Patience is a virtue here, because issues like this one take time to get people to look at it or to begin to provide troubleshooting guidelines.

Comment: I understand the (real) need to keep spammers at bay, and I know there are other people out there in need of help who feel locked out by their lack of Linux knowledge.  Even asking a question that won't get deleted or downvoted is hard, not nothing.  

For the sake of those other newbs like me, Any tips on getting rep without knowing much (or anything) about Linux?

Comment: @jenboi just ask good questions?  We all started from somewhere with little or no knowledge.  Asking questions is the beginning of knowledge, so just post good questions and you will be fine.  And you will learn things as time continues!